# Errors in VS Code console under Svelte Intellisense Language Service

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I am constantly getting errors like the ones below in VS Code console under the Svelte Intellisense Language Service dropdown. If I restart VS Code they go away for a while but begin to show up again.

**Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix? Thanks---**

```
[Error - 9:30:36 AM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/hover failed with message: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 9:30:48 AM] Request textDocument/hover failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/hover failed with message: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 9:47:53 AM] Request textDocument/completion failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/completion failed with message: Cannot read property 'slots' of undefined
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 9:47:56 AM] Request textDocument/completion failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/completion failed with message: Cannot read property 'slots' of undefined
  Code: -32603
```

Comment: Did you find the reason?

Comment: I've been having this problem too...

Comment: Did you open an issue in GitHub? A post on Stack Overflow is much less likely to come to the maintainers' attention.

Comment: it's 2021 and for me, I still don't know what happens with this, what's the cause of it?

Answer (score 1):

The extension "svelte-intellisense" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ardenivanov.svelte-intellisense) seems to be out of date, the latest release was in 2019, and the official Svelte extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) should cover all the features.

Removing the "svelte-intellisense" extension worked for me.